# Mozilla firefox problem on window.getSelection()

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

In my code I've tried to get the window.getSelection() and set it in a variable to save my current focusNode and offset when the contenteditable div onBlur is fired. It is working in chrome browser. However, in mozilla the window.getSelection() fires after on click event.

```
onBlur(): void {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  this.savedCaret = [selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selection.focusNode` is an [experimental feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Conventions_definitions#Experimental) on Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusNode. The first link describes an experimental feature:

> [An experimental feature is] in the process of being added to the web platform.

You will probably have to write a similar feature without the `Selection` object. I hope this can help you.

Comment: focusNode is no longer a experimental feature in Firefox, but the issue still remains.